# Java XML: Avoid relative systemId expansion against user.dir

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xerces

Consider the following example XML:

```
<book xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xsd/book.xsd" />
```

When parsing this xml file with standard JAXP APIs (which will often use a Xerces implementation), the "xsd/book.xsd" systemId will get "resolved" against the user directory and will result in `file:///home/user/xsd/book.xsd`.

For xerces, this behavior is implemented here: https://github.com/apache/xerces2-j/blob/cf0c517a41b31b0242b96ab1af9627a3ab07fcd2/src/org/apache/xerces/impl/XMLEntityManager.java#L1894

To **workaround** this, we're currently using an `EntityResolver2` to extract the original, relative systemId out of the absolute URI `file:///home/user/xsd/book.xsd` but this is really hacky.

**Question:**
Is there better way, e.g. by disabling this strange "userdir"-behavior and just keep the relative systemIds as they are?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the schemaLocation to be interpreted as relative to the base URI of the source document, just make sure that the base URI of the source document is known to Xerces. For example, don't supply the input as a FileInputStream with no known system Id. It will only use the current directory as a fallback if it doesn't know where the input file is located.

Comment: Thanks, Michael, for your high-profile answer, much appreciated. You're right, I am using an InputStream in this case and of course there's no way for xerces to resolve it to the correct absolute path in this case. Instead, my goal is that it stays unchanged (and therefore meaningless to Xerces) because I know how to resolve it in my EntityResolver2 to the correct absolute path. So I am searching a way that my EntityResolver2 gets the relative, original systemId from the xml (in the above example: "xsd/book.xsd"). I did some research in the Xerces code but have not been successful so far.

Comment: Try setting a dummy base URI (such as `http://dummy/`) that your EntityResolver recognizes.

Comment: How to set a baseURI in Xerces?

Comment: Set the `systemId` property of the `InputSource` object.